# I am seeking a SCP/SFTP client for iOS devices

Tags: applications, ios, ssh

There are clients for telnet and SSH but I couldn't find any app including SCP. Is there any?

Comment: The iOS app sandbox makes this less useful than you might expect at first glance. What are you going to do with this app that can't be done by ssh into a server or computer and copying files to iDisk / DropBox / WebDAV using ssh?

Comment: Administering local servers without internet access, modifying configuration files, for instance.

Comment: @bmike - If you jailbreak, it fixes the sandbox issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something more useful. [Textastic](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id383577124?mt=8) works with SFTP.

Answer (score 4):

I use a combination of two apps to administer local servers without internet access. There might be a good scp/sftp app I don't know - but AirSharing does file serving so well that I just turn it on then ssh into the server. From there, I sftp/curl the files I need back from the iOS file server.

1. [Prompt](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prompt/id421507115?mt=8) - a great ssh app by [Panic](http://panic.com/).
2. [Air Sharing](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-sharing/id289943355?mt=8) Pro - a file server that [supports webdav/sftp/curl/http](http://avatron.com/apps/air-sharing)

Comment: Add to my list, screens app and an airport express, and I'm at home in most data centers. iPad plus bluetooth keyboard FTW.